# z-index and tooltip

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a tooltip in css, it is working, but I have a problem when the tooltips appear, because the text in the p tag its is showing over the span content "the tooltip" I want to show over all the content.
Ive been trying withh z-index, also defining the position in al the tags, but cant understand why it is not working.
I would apreciate any tip about how can I solve it.

I have the next html structure

```
 <div>
        <a class="tooltip">
            <p>Test1</p>
            <span>saassa</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
a.tooltip {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px blue;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bcd9db;
    z-index: 20;
}

a.tooltip p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline;
    color: #006565;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}

a.tooltip > span {
    width: 25em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -85px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #000000;
    background: #FBF5E6;
    border: 2px solid #CFB57C;
    z-index: 1000;
}

a.tooltip:hover > span {
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -260px;
    background: #fbf5e6;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

I have loadded to Fiddle, so you can see it, just hover in any of the three first links and you will see that cant see all the content of the divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/mtzcq/3/

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `z-index` from `a.tooltip`, and `a.tooltip p`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtzcq/7/

That worked for me in Firefox for Mac

Comment: Thanks Coopersita
This solves it in the Fiddle, but not in my website.
Any explanation about why deleting that 2 properties looks better?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why. This page has a bunch of examples of z-index, vs no z-index, and with different values: http://css-class.com/test/css/visformatting/layers/z-index.htm This other article may help as well: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/ Suerte!

Comment: I would delete all the z-indexes that you have, and start adding them just to the items that are above something else. You may have some z-index set somewhere else, and that's why your page is affected, but not the fiddle.

Comment: I readed this morning the one in Smashing Magazine, but it isnt similar to my problem, ill read the other one. Thank you again

Comment: Found the solution, I am using Zurb Foundation. The framework uses a class with the same name as tooltip. So I just changed and it solve it.

Answer (score 1):

En el código html tienes que quitar dentro del span los `H6`

Comment: That way you don't solve my problem. You has just moved the div out of the p.

Comment: No sé como puedo darte puntos, yo soy un novato aquí y creo que no tengo puntos para dar.

Comment: No creo que Bernardao tenga los suficientes puntos como para poder votar.

Comment: Pero que quieres en si? Que no se vean los h6?

Comment: Lo que quiero es lo que ha conseguido Coopersita, que el tooltip aparezca por encima de todo, pero en mi web la etiqueta <a> se lee por encima de todo.

Comment: Tienes alguna etiqueta que hace conflicto tienes que ir probando con !important  en algunas partes del hoover

Comment: I just set all the tags in the a:hover span with !important, but it isnt working

Comment: Is necesary all css of your website

Comment: Ok problema resuelto, muchas veces es mejor renombrar. ami me sucedió algo parecido hace unos pocos días con blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the instances of "Z-index" except for the one in the a.tooltip > span

Comment: Thats how I had my site, and again I have just set it the same way. Only is another z-index in my site and its on the header, but is not displaying in same zone.